# Error in assigning index value using an object

Tags: c#

This is my moving average class. I get a run time error on this line of code: _ma[_period - 1].ClosingPrice = sum / _period;

```
public class MyMovingAverage 
    {
        private static DateClose[] _ma;
        private static int _period;
        private static DateClose[] _source;
        private static DateClose _dateClose;

        public static DateClose[] MovingAverage(int period, DateClose[] source)
        {
            _period = period;
            _source = source;
            _ma = new DateClose[_source.Length];
            decimal sum = 0;

            for (int bar = 0; bar < _period; bar++)
            {
                _dateClose = _source[bar];
                sum += _dateClose.ClosingPrice;
            }
            _ma[_period - 1].ClosingPrice = sum / _period; //RUN TIME ERROR HERE
            _ma[_period - 1].Time = _dateClose.Time;

            for (int bar = _period; bar < _source.Length; bar++)
            {
                _dateClose = _source[bar];

                _ma[bar].ClosingPrice = _ma[bar - 1].ClosingPrice + _dateClose.ClosingPrice / _period
                                          - _source[bar - _period].ClosingPrice / _period;
            }
            return _ma;
        }
    }
```

Here is the DateClose class:

```
public class DateClose
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public decimal ClosingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Exception thrown in above code (where it is marked), is `System.NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It would help if you could write what kind of error you get. From the code I would guess that "_period" is 0 and you get DivideByZero exception or maybe IndexOutOfRange for having invalid index for "_ma".

Comment: @Jure this is the error 

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in BuySell_20190423.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create an object for item in `_ma` array, before setting its properties.

Before `_ma[_period - 1].ClosingPrice = sum / _period;` you should do:

```
_ma[_period - 1] = new DateClose();
```

and then

```
_ma[_period - 1].ClosingPrice = sum / _period;
```

and other code...